# Use of “as” in adverbial introductory phrase

Tags: modifiers

Isn't this incorrect:

> As a young boy his family moved …

Isn't this saying the the family moved as (when) it was young. A comma after boy fixes it, I believe, but it still seems a misplaced or faulty modifier.

Comment: Voting to close as "too localised". At first this looked like a peeve to me, but adding a comma isn't going to help anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Depending on how the sentence progresses, it could be rewritten: “As a young boy *he* moved *with his family* …”.